# Non-static method CController::createUrl() should not be called statically yii

Tags: php, yii, static

For php version 5.3. This line is working fine.

```
<?php echo CController::createUrl('/Reload/data')?>
```

But when I updated my php to 5.4. I am getting

**Non-static method CController::createUrl() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context**

What should I have to do to make it work in yii?

Comment: Is this code in a view, widget or something else?

Comment: @topher yes it is in widget.

Comment: @PrashantSharma take a look at this: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/67942-non-static-method-ccontrollercreateurl-should-not-be-called-statically/

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a controller object. Assuming you are working within a view you can use `$this` to access the current controller object:

```
<?php $this->createUrl('/Reload/data')?>
```

Within a widget you can use [`$this->controller`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#controller-detail):

```
<?php $this->controller->createUrl('/Reload/data')?>
```

If not, you can use [`Yii::app()->controller`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#controller-detail):

```
<?php Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('/Reload/data')?>
```

Comment: Is there is any other way to do this? I have to change a lot of code for this.

Comment: The correct method would be to change your code. You can disable strict standards by removing `E_STRICT` from `error_reporting()` to hide these notices but your code will break in future php versions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure how this line would work even in PHP 5.3 since you are calling a non static method in a static context. CController::createUrl() actually references $this...

Anyway, back to your main point : in Yii1 you can also manage your URLs with [CApplication::createUrl()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createUrl-detail), and the Application object is available anywhere in your code.